# MVC model talks to view

Tags: design-patterns, model-view-controller

Up until now I have been using the `CakePHP` framework. Which on their offical website states:

```
Clean MVC Conventions
```

For those of you who doesn't know `CakePHP` the framework works as follow:

`Model` (database access) `View`(a sort of dump containing all the HTML but still uses php components to create many of the links, images and so on), `Controller` (manage the access between the model and the view).

Now I wanted to create my own "Mini" `framework` and thought I would take a look at what MVC was and how to keep the offical conventions!

I quickly realized that something was wrong.

Many of the sites and even here on SO suggest that the `Model` talks directly to the `View`(or the other way around). And the `Controller` only comes into play if or when data should be modified.

My question is how is the real relation ship between `Model` `view` and `controller`. Has `Cakephp` misunderstood or modified the offical conventions of the `design pattern` and should `Models` and `controllers` be created according to the `view` and not the other way around?

I hope someone is able to clear these things up for me I am quite confused right now :)

Comment: I believe references to "Model used directly by the View" refer specifically to `ViewModels`, which are projections of data, specifically tailored to one or more views, e.g. in the context of `MVVM`.

Comment: I believe that people who don't know where `ViewModel` concept comes from, should read about [presentation models](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PresentationModel.html). And views are supposed to observe model layer (which in web applications is kinda unpractical) and pull the new data from model layer.

Comment: @tereško meaning that cakephp is doing it the right way by having the Controller handle ALL request back and forward from the model?

Comment: It was response to Stuart. As for `"has Cakephp misunderstood or modified the official conventions"`, the answer is "yes". Instead of implementing anything like MVC, it opted to mimics Rails-like structure, where goal was quick prototyping of throw-away code. Views are not templates. Model is a layer, not a name for active record instance. And controllers do not contain application logic.

Comment: @tereško to make sure we don't over comment is it possible that you could give an answer to how it should be implemented when talking web?